# Spring Security - how can I ask invoke access control methods directly?

Tags: java, spring-security, authorization

There's a lot of documentation on how to use jsp tags, aop, annotations, the application context, and all of these sorts of things... but how do I access the access control methods directly? What class do I need to create, if any? Is there hidden bean I need to be aware of? It doesn't seem like `SecurityContextHolder` is the right place to look.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
if(springSecurityObject.isAuthorized("hasAnyRole('DIRECTOR', 'ADMIN')")) {
    // ... do something
}
```

Or even better:

```
if(springSecurityObject.hasAnyRole('DIRECTOR', 'ADMIN')) {
    // ... do something
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** It seems like the spring security people are using the granted authorities on the user object itself:

https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-security/taglibs/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/taglibs/authz/AbstractAuthorizeTag.java?r=fc399af136492c6c37cdddca6d44e5fe57f69680

I think it would probably have been helpful if they abstracted out a ton of this code and put it into a nice set of classes instead - something that both the tag libraries and actual users could use. They are private helper methods after all... a common smell that they should probably exist in some classes instead.

Since they are doing the plumbing manually, I guess I have to assume that what I want doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is invoking your `UserDetailsService` manually, calling `getAuthorities()` on the returned `Authentication` and then calling `contains()` or `containsAll()` on the returned collection.

So you'd have something like:

```
final UserDetails jimmyDetails = myDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("Jimmy");
final Collection<GrantedAuthority> jimmyAuthorities = jimmyDetails.getAuthorities();

// make it a Collection<String> by iterating and calling .getAuthority()

plainAuthorities.contains("ROLE_YOU_NEED_TO_CHECK_FOR");
```

Writing your own helper methods that do this would not be too hard, although I agree that having them in the API would be nice.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I thought. I've been doing something along these lines myself too. I'll give you the checkmark because this seems like the only answer. It is a shame though because there's a lot of code in the jsp tags that I highlighted that is probably coded in many spots in the framework, and probably should be put into some standard classes for both the framework and for people to use. Just a missed opportunity really.